# Cree un programa en bash que permita sumar el primer millón de números,

Tags: linux

Tengo que hacer un bash que sume el primer millón de números.

¿Como podría hacerlo?, no pude asistir las clases donde explicaron la temática del base :(

Comment: Hola, recuerda que estás en StackOverflow en ESPAÑOL. Deberías revisar la sección [ask] y realizar el [tour] (ademas de [edit] tu pregunta y traducirla)

Comment: No entiendo el bien recibimiento de la pregunta. El OP no demostro su intento y en ese caso este no es el sitio adecuado para ayudarle (por mas que queramos). Hasta donde tenia entendido, este tipo de dudas no encajan en el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

La suma de los primeros `n` números está dada por la expresión `s=n*(n+1)/2`, por lo que la forma más eficiente y muy básica de hacer tu programa es simplemente:

```
echo "$((1000000 * (1000000 + 1) / 2))"
```

---

Si como ejercicio académico necesitas trabajar iterando:

```
seq 1 1000000 | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Donde:

- Con `seq 1 1000000` obtienes el rango desde el 1 al millón.
- Con `paste -sd+` obtienes cada número de la secuencia anterior y le insertas un signo de más al final para que tengas algo así `1+2+3+4+5+...`
- Con `bc` ejecutas la suma.

---

Usando un ciclo `while`:

```
i=1
sum=0

while [ $i -le 1000000 ]
do
  sum=$((sum + $i))
  i=$((i + 1))
done

echo $sum
```

---

Usando un ciclo `for`:

```
sum=0

for i in {1..1000000}
do        
  sum=$((sum + $i)) 
done

echo $sum
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho.